# Border solid style with shortened dimensions

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a border for the top of a `div` element. The border is a 1px thick solid line, and it is to make a noticeable division between the footer and the website content. However, I don't want the border to span the whole width of the footer. I'd instead like it to be shorter (by maybe 10 pixels or so on each side) and centered. How should I do this? Does it require me to use an image?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mean something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/8ZSSc/

Or, if you always wanted exactly 10px short of each side regardless of page size:

http://jsfiddle.net/8ZSSc/2/

Comment: I just realized you basically posted the same thing as me :) +1 for that!

Answer (score 2):

Just use the `<hr />` tag to make a horizontal line, and set the width for that.

Comment: Would this be the most proper way to do this? The div method seems like it is a little excessive. Are there any pros to using a div (for extensibility or whatever)?

Comment: <hr /> isn't commonly used any more, in my opinion div's are better.

Comment: @Teak "commonly used" shouldn't affect the propensity to do something. 
`<hr/>` is actually more semantic here, IMO.

Comment: For one thing <hr /> shows up different on all browsers. Another thing <hr /> can not be used if you are using strict HTML/XHTML.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are looking for something like this:

```
<div style="width: 95%; border-top: 1px solid; margin: auto;"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add another div above the footer, add a top border, and use padding to make it narrower:

```
.footer-line {
    border-top: ...
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have another very skinny `div`, just above the footer.

Comment: Or like kinakuta says and have a smaller `div` with a top border. (probably better...)